# Select sem repetir dados

Tags: php, mysql, select

Ola pessoal estou desenvolvendo um site para um projeto musical e estou tendo dificuldade com o select, é o seguinte, tenho 2 tabelas uma chamada album que contem informações do cd (artwork, titulo do disco, nome das musicas, etc), a outra tabela chama album_links que tem os links de onde o cd estará disponivel para comprar (amazon, bandcamp, itunes, etc).

Eu fiz um select na tabela album e todas informações aparecem normalmente, porém na tabela album_links quando é feito o select os dados se repetem se tiver mais de um cd cadastrado.

A ideia é que só mostre os links para cada cd cadastrado.
Ex:

CD 1
link1
link2
link3

CD 2
link1

A unica tabela que tem chave estrangeira (referente a tabela album) é a tabela album_links, ja tentei fazer um inner join entre as duas tabelas, e tambem outros selects, mas por enquanto sem sucesso.

Tive o mesmo problema em outro projeto quando fui desenvolver uma galeria de fotos, os dados se repetiam e eu ainda não consegui resolver esse problema tambem.

Alguém tem ideia do que pode ser?

Aqui esta o código do Front-End

```
public function listing() {
    $ListRelease = new ModelsRead();
    $ListRelease->ExeRead('album');
    $this->Result = $ListRelease->getResult();
    return $this->Result;
}

public function listingLinks() {
    $ListReleaseLink = new ModelsRead();
    $ListReleaseLink->ExeRead('album_links');        
    $this->Result = $ListReleaseLink->getResult();
    return $this->Result;
}
```

Nas duas funções o ExeRead faz: SELECT * FROM tabela

A classe ModelsRead tem as funções

```
public function ExeRead($Table, $Terms = null, $ParseString = null) {
    if (!empty($ParseString)):
        parse_str($ParseString, $this->Values);
    endif;
    $this->Select = "SELECT * FROM {$Table} {$Terms}";
    $this->ExecuteInstruction();
}
public function fullRead($Query, $ParseString = null) {
    $this->Select = (string) $Query;
    if(!empty($ParseString)):
        parse_str($ParseString, $this->Values);
    endif;
    $this->ExecuteInstruction();
}
```

Banco de dados: mysql

Aqui esta o inner join que eu tentei fazer:

```
public function listingLinks() {
    $ListReleaseLink = new ModelsRead();
    $ListReleaseLink->fullRead("SELECT alblink.*, alb.album_title album FROM 
    album_links alblink
                            INNER JOIN album alb ON alb.id = alblink.album_id");
    $this->Result = $ListReleaseLink->getResult();
    return $this->Result;
}
```

Porem ele repete os dados, o resultado que eu quero é que para cada album mostre os respectivos links cadastrados.

```
    Tabela album
    id
    album_title
    picture
    album_tracks    
    album_members   
    album_release_date
    producers
    studio
    created
    modified

    Tabela album_links
    id
    name
    picture
    link
    album_id
    created
    modified
```

Nesse projeto estou utilizando padrão MVC

Comment: Poste os códigos para podermos te ajudar. Especifique mais seu problema. Qual linguagem está usando?

Comment: Estou usando PHP Orientado a Objetos

Comment: Poste seu código para eu ver o que está fazendo.

Comment: Está usando um plugin? Ou a classe ModelsRead() foi você que fez?

Comment: Não, não estou usando nenhum plugin

Comment: Sim, a classe ModelsRead foi eu que criei

Comment: Toda a estrutura que eu estou usando é um "mini" framework que eu desenvolvi em um curso.

Comment: Sem código não conseguimos entender. No entanto o que me parece: - Um join na tabela mal feito ou nem feito. - Uma cláusula distinct poderá resolver o problema. Isto no contexto da query de sql.

Comment: @RobsonLuizDosSantos coloque a consulta com o inner join que você estava fazendo para analisarmos.

Comment: Isto não responde à pergunta. Quando você tiver [reputação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) suficiente, você vai poder deixar [comentários em qualquer post](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) mas, até lá, escreva apenas resposta que não [dependam de mais informações de quem perguntou](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [Da Revisão](/review/low-quality-posts/170411)

Comment: Uma coisa que eu acho é que não estou sabendo fazer o inner join corretamente, pois o que eu tentei ele repetiu os dados, e a ideia é que ao fazer o select mostre as informações do cd cadastrado e os links cadastrados para esse cd. Ex: CD1 link1 link2 link3, CD2 link1 link2, uma outra coisa que eu ja pensei tambem é o problema pode estar no relacionamento das tabelas.

Comment: Alem do inner join postei tambem a estrutura das tabelas

Answer (score 0):

Para ele nao repetir os dados no inner join voce só precisa colocar no final da sintaxe "group by album_id"

Comment: Já tentei fazer isso também, porém o que acontece é o seguinte, na tabela album tem 2 cds cadastrados, e na tabela album_links tem 5 links apenas para o cd 1 , quando eu coloco o group by album_id, ele retorna apenas um link e duplica o resultado para os 2 cds.